# Elasticsearch grouping by nested fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there a way to group by nested fields and perform aggregation on a non-nested fields??

I have data like this in ES

```
{
    "_index": "bighalf",
    "_type": "excel",
    "_id": "AVE0rgXqe0-x669Gsae3",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "Name": "Marsh",
      "date": "2015-11-07T10:47:14",
      "grade": 9,
      "year": 2016,
      "marks": 70,
      "subject": "Mathematics",
      "Gender": "male",
      "dob": "22/11/2000",
      "sprint": [
        {
          "sprintdate": "2015-11-06T22:30:00",
          "sprintname": "changed",
          "sprintpoints": 52
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "bighalf",
    "_type": "excel",
    "_id": "AVE0rvTHe0-x669Gsae5",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "Name": "Taylor",
      "date": "2015-11-07T10:47:14",
      "grade": 9,
      "year": 2016,
      "marks": 54,
      "subject": "Mathematics",
      "Gender": "male",
      "dob": "22/11/2000",
      "sprint": [
        {
          "sprintdate": "2015-11-07T22:30:00",
          "sprintname": "jira",
          "sprintpoints": 52
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I wanted to group by `sprintname` and find sum of `marks`

I tried like this:

```
SumBuilder sumGrades = AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_grade").field("grade");
NestedBuilder nested = AggregationBuilders.nested("nested").path("sprint")
.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("by_sprint").field("sprint.sprintname").subAggregation(sumGrades));
String names[] = { "changed", "jira" };
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(
QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("sprint",QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("sprint.sprintname", names))));
FilterAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.filter("agg").filter(query).subAggregation(nested);
```

the `sum_grade` did not work for me. But I changed field(`grade`) with nested field (`sprintpoints`) and it worked But my requirement is to find `sum("grade")` and group by `sprint.sprintname`.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the `sprint` field? `curl -XGET localhost:9200/bighalf/_mapping/excel/field/sprint`

Comment: If say localhost:9200/bighalf/_mapping/excel/field/sprint. Am not getting any mappings. But if I say http://localhost:9200/bighalf/_mapping/excel. Am getting all the mappings.

Comment: { "sprint": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "sprintdate": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
              },
              "sprintname": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "sprintpoints": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `sprint` field is of `nested` type, in your aggregation you need to use the [`reverse_nested` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) in order to "jump back" at the root document from within your nested ones. It goes like this:

```
SumBuilder sumGrades = AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_grade").field("grade");

ReverseNestedBuilder backToGrades = AggregationBuilders.reverseNested("spring_to_grade")
    .subAggregation(sumGrades);

TermsBuilder bySprint = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_sprint")
    .field("sprint.sprintname").subAggregation(backToGrades)

NestedBuilder nested = AggregationBuilders.nested("nested").path("sprint")
    .subAggregation(bySprint);

String names[] = { "changed", "jira" };
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(
QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("sprint",QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("sprint.sprintname", names))));
FilterAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.filter("agg").filter(query).subAggregation(nested);
```

Comment: Did you have any chance with this?

Comment: Thanks Val. It helped lot to fix the issue.